# React modal animation modal keyframes

Tags: css, react-modal

I am using react modal for models in my react application. I would like to add some animations to them for when they appear. I am using. css3 keyframes to animate my modals.

```
@keyframes modalSlide {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

This gives nice sliding effect combined with animation-duration but it slides down from the top. How do I change so it slides up from the bottom instead?

Comment: Remove the minus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try positive value for translateY in keyframes `from`:

```
@keyframes modalSlide {
  from {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`translateY` means moving the element on the `y` axis. Where your element is positioned by default, the value on `y` axis ( as well as on the other two axis ) is `0`.

So if you want to move your element up on the `y` axis, you write `(-distance)`. If you want to move it down, you write `(+distance)`

And so, if you want your element to come from 'below', you need to first position it below it's default position. By using a positive value. And then attach the animation to it.

Thus add `transform:translateY(50%)` also  to the modal itself to overwrite it's default position.

```css
@keyframes modalSlide {
  from {
    transform: translateY(50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal {
background:red;
width:10px;
height:100px;
animation:modalSlide 0.5s ease-out forwards;
transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
</div>
```